# What are the challenges of making a CSS framework?

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I am studying some popular CSS frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation etc. I pointed some out, and I'm willing to make my own CSS framework whether for my own projects or in later for free distribution. As I'm a front-end developer in most of the cases, I'm a bit slow with JavaScripts. So in my study I found some challenges in making a new CSS framework, like:

- JavaScripts integration for a nice, clean and easy-to-use front-end
- Common and general values for a fixed layout
- The menu CSS

And also I found some features a bit challenging, like:

- Responsive grids (I loved it)

But is there any checklist that should be fulfilled in CSS framework?

Comment: Are you going to use plain css? I feel like it does not make sense going that path. It should be built from sass or less.

Comment: @MonNoval: Actually yes. But I'll keep your comment in mind, when I'll proceed inshALLAH. Thanks.

Comment: I urge you to get the hang of either Less or SASS/SCSS, it will open your mind to a wide range of stuff. Features is one thing, majority is more to maintainability and extensibility. 

Quick example of SASS is the @extend http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend (amazingly insane coding without this)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try yoeman to help you create your own css framework quickly and easily.

Here is the link on the details of Yoeman generator:

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Generators